# ngSelect with backend API only if user types more than 4 characters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngselect

Can we use ngSelect & get datasource from backend API call in AngularJS. Backend API should be called only when user types more than 4 characters(the reason i m trying to implement this, because my datasource is pretty huge & i didn't want to load everything)

[https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect][1]

I initially wanted to  use ngTypeahead but that doesn't support multiselect feature.

Comment: Can you please share piece of code? HTML and Function which calls API.

Comment: Actually i am not quite familiar with ngselect directive & don't have any code written . I am trying to figure out the best way to achieve multiselect autocomplete functionality but where ever i looked i only noticed that entire dataset is initially loaded. I already have function & API's setup & working as designed but i am not sure if we can achieve my requirement like loading the dataset only after user enters 4 characters(backend call should happen only after user types atleast 4 characters)

Comment: https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect